# Custom dictionary items on pdf signature

Tags: c#, itext, sign

I am signing a pdf document using iTextSharp 5. This is working as expected. I am now trying to add some custom properties (dictionary items) to the signature.

```
PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, signedPdf, '\0', null, true);
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;

// Adding the custom properties
PdfDictionary dict = new PdfDictionary();
dict.Put(new PdfName("SomeKey"), new PdfString("SomeValue"));
// ... more keys and values
sap.CryptoDictionary = dict;

// to make some of the parameters clear, these are the types. 
// implementation was skipped for clarity, but is already working in our product though
ITSAClient tsaClient = ...
ICollection<ICrlClient> crlClients = ...
IOcspClient ocspClient = ...
IExternalSignature externalSignature = ...

// adding the signature to the document
MakeSignature.SignDetached(sap, externalSignature, chain, crlClients, ocspClient, tsaClient,
                        certSize, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

I tried to use RUPS to find my extra properties in the document but I am not able to find them.

Also, when opening the pdf again, the data cannot be found using the following code (but I obviously can't confirm that this is the right code for the job):

```
PdfDictionary sigDict = reader.AcroFields.GetSignatureDictionary(signature name);
```

Of course I could serialize my properties into json and put them in a hidden text field, that is my fallback scenario. But I would have to protect that field using the signature etc. I presume this approach is more the actual way pdf was designed.

For this particular product it is not possible to upgrade to iText 7 for ominous reasons. We do however have a newer product in which I need to add the same functionality later on which does use iText 7.

Is there someone who knows whether this is the correct approach and what I am missing? I can't really find good coding examples on pdf dictionaries combined with signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your custom keys in a dictionary you then assign to the `CryptoDictionary` of the signature appearance

```
PdfDictionary dict = new PdfDictionary();
dict.Put(new PdfName("SomeKey"), new PdfString("SomeValue"));
// ... more keys and values
sap.CryptoDictionary = dict;
```

and later you call the `SignDetached` utility method:

```
MakeSignature.SignDetached(sap, externalSignature, chain, crlClients, ocspClient, tsaClient,
                    certSize, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Unfortunately (for you), `MakeSignature.SignDetached` itself creates a new dictionary it eventually assigns to the `CryptoDictionary` of the signature appearance:

```
PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, sigtype == CryptoStandard.CADES ? PdfName.ETSI_CADES_DETACHED : PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
dic.Reason = sap.Reason;
dic.Location = sap.Location;
dic.SignatureCreator = sap.SignatureCreator;
dic.Contact = sap.Contact;
dic.Date = new PdfDate(sap.SignDate); // time-stamp will over-rule this
sap.CryptoDictionary = dic;
```

Thus, your dictionary with its custom values is dropped!

To add custom values to the signature value dictionary you have to change your approach. You could

- copy the whole code from the `MakeSignature.SignDetached` into your code and add your custom keys and values; or
- use `MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer` instead of `MakeSignature.SignDetached`. This utility method is given a `IExternalSignatureContainer` implementation instead of the `IExternalSignature` implementation and other parameters, and that interface has a callback method

  ```
  /**
   * Modifies the signature dictionary to suit the container. At least the keys PdfName.FILTER and 
   * PdfName.SUBFILTER will have to be set.
   * @param signDic the signature dictionary
   */
  void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic);
  ```

  You can add your custom keys here. Obviously, though, you'll have to copy some code from `MakeSignature.SignDetached` into your `IExternalSignatureContainer` implementation as well.

If you do not know the code in `MakeSignature.SignDetached` and its meaning well, the former option will be easier for you. The latter option, on the other hand, would be a bit cleaner as it allows you to leave some low-level details in the utility method.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Sorry for the late reply, somehow the notifications have gone unnoticed. I will try implementing this somewhere in the near future. My current solution is to add something to the signing location which is obviously not very elegant.